# How do I remove all background color in python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, frame

I think the background color is the issue, however, it might not be. I am trying to make the background of the frame and canvas image so that you can see the text before it is covered by the rounded side.

Here is an image of what I currently have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLHbq.jpg

There are other spacing issues, but I am focusing on the color of the background needing to be transparent.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think canvas has not transparent background.

Comment: I figured out he answer - you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't...

[Configure tkinter/ttk widgets with transparent backgrounds, ttk frame background colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011406/configure-tkinter-ttk-widgets-with-transparent-backgrounds-ttk-frame-background)

After a couple hours of looking stuff up I figured out it is impossible.