# Frame with no background in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a canvas with a background image in Tkinter. I want to add a frame with no background so that I can arrange elements in the window, but, still see the background behind these elements. When I use something similar to the code below, i.e., without specifying the bg color, I get a frame with a grey background. How do I turn it to no background at all?

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x560")

bgImg=Image.open("data/bg.png")
bgImg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImg)
canvas=tk.Canvas(root,width=800,height=560)
canvas.pack(expand = False, fill = "both")

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bgImg, anchor="nw")

frame=tk.Frame(canvas,width=50,height=50)
frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

There may* be platform-dependent options, like [this](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M6).
(* In Lubuntu 18.04 & python 3.6.9, they don't seem to work,
so I can't test them.)

One cross-platform(?) option, is to use Canvas.
Then draw images* on the canvas, instead of using widgets.
(*whose alpha channel, determines their transparent pixels)
This will draw foreground/background elements correctly,
& Canvas has enough functionality to control elements on it
(but will need work, if you want to emulate full widgets).

Canvas offers various `create_xyz` methods, where xyz:
`arc`, `line`, `rectangle`, `bitmap`, `oval`, `text`, `image`, `polygon`,
`window` (<- read 'widget')*.
These return an id, that represents the item in the canvas.
Items can also be associated in groups, represented by tags.

* When using widgets in Canvas, there are some restrictions:
https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M163
"Note: due to restrictions in the ways that windows are managed,
it is not possible to draw other graphical items
(such as lines and images) on top of window items.
A window item always obscures any graphics that overlap it,
regardless of their order in the display list."

Items in a canvas, can be configured & have event-handlers:
`itemconfig` / `itemcget`
`tag_bind` / `tag_unbind`
These can use either an individual item-id, or* a group-tag.
(* despite the 'tag_' in the name, they also take item-ids)

Many other Canvas methods work with item-ids or group-tags
(e.g. `move`, `delete`,).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# Note:
# If the images overlap exactly (same position & extent),
# the bottom one will never? get any events.
# Maybe events can be propagated, not sure right now.

fgImg = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file='media/fg.png')
fgImgId = canvas.create_image(
  80, 80, anchor=tk.NW, image=fgImg
)
canvas.tag_bind(
  fgImgId,
  '<ButtonRelease-1>',
  lambda e: canvas.tag_raise(fgImgId)
)

bgImg = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file='media/bg.png')
bgImgId = canvas.create_image(
  0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=bgImg
)
canvas.tag_bind(
  bgImgId,
  '<ButtonRelease-1>',
  lambda e: canvas.tag_raise(bgImgId)
)

root.mainloop()
```

There are more StackOverflow questions about this, e.g.:
[transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window)
[python-tkinter-label-background-transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461045/python-tkinter-label-background-transparent)
[configure-tkinter-ttk-widgets-with-transparent-backgrounds-ttk-frame-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011406/configure-tkinter-ttk-widgets-with-transparent-backgrounds-ttk-frame-background)
and more.

You might also want to look into other gui toolkits.
(e.g. wxpython*, pyqt, )
(*[Here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Make-Label-Text-background-default-color-transparent-using-tkinter-in-python) it says, that it has a `SetTransparent` command.)